# Spring Integration, Message Endpoints vs Message Routers

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, integration

I am trying to understand the differents between these two ?

are these actually two different elements / building blocks in Spring Integration ?
how Routers are different from Message Endpoints?
is Message Router is composed of Message Channels & Message Endpoints ?

please any experts share your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to consider to learn more about Enterprise Integration Patterns: https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/

There are 3 main concepts: messages, endpoints and channel between them.
Everything what can consume messages from the channel is called *endpoint* - event-driven, pollable or reactive. The *router* is one of endpoint types, along side with service activator, splitter, aggregator, filter etc.

So, answering shortly to your question - the `endpoint` is a messaging abstraction to consume messages from input channel(s) and process them. The `router` is a particular endpoint implementation with its own specific logic.

There are much more internal details and difference between endpoints, but that's already outside of this SO thread.